# Saving Django user forms without changing the password

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm maintaining a Django application and have encountered a bug where if a user edits their profile then their password is corrupted; it seems that set_password is not being used and so the password is set to an unencrypted value which is hardcoded in the form. It's not clear how I could change the existing setup to get around this nuisance, and would welcome any suggestions. The update code looks like this:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userform = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)

        if profileform.is_valid():
            profileform.save()
        if userform.is_valid():
            userform.save()

        return redirect('user_profile_page')
    else:
        profileform = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        userform = UserForm(instance=user)
        render(request, 'profiles/edit_profile.html', {'profileform': profileform, 'userform': userform})

return render(request, 'profiles/edit_profile.html', {'profileform': profileform, 'userform': userform})
```

Then, the userform which is causing the problem contains this odd-looking code:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('last_login', 'date_joined', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff')

    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'value': '00000000000000000'}))
```

I'm not really sure what the value attr in password is meant to be doing. Anyway, I tried to modify this by adding the following to the UserForm:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
    password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
    if len(password) > 0 and password != '00000000000000000':
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

I had no luck with this either, and if I simply omit the password field from the userform or the relevant html then the form does not validate.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="wide">
    {% csrf_token %}
    .....
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    {{ userform.password }}
```

Can anyone suggest how this might be cleaned up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate form for editing the password and remove it from this one. Add `password` to the `exclude` list and remove the field declaration.

Comment: Thanks! I had previously tried that but without success - evidently I had made another mistake and thus assumed that the method hadn't done the trick.